# How do I use the "Ubuntu One" folder name in scripts?

Tags: ubuntu-one, files

I use Ubuntu One to sync a Gnumeric spreadsheet. I like to launch the spreadsheet via a script, something like `gnumeric /home/daves/data/test.gnumeric`

The file in question is now in my Ubuntu One folder. However I cannot use the Ubuntu One name in a script as the resulting script when run reports 'no such file or directory', presumably due to the space in the name Ubuntu One. How can I successfully path this in a script please?

Answer (score 2):

If it is the space bugging you you need to escape it. You can use auto-complete for it.

Example:

```
$ls
AR Tonelico   Cowon J3  Desktop  lost+found  user_guide_8455_dvb.pdf
```

'Cowon J3' has a space in it. If I would want to cd into 'Cowon J3' I type 'cd C' and hit tab. Linux fills in the rest and you will see a \ added in front of the space so it would look like this:

```
cd Cowon\ J3/
```

Same goes for other special characters like the \ itself (you use 2x \ to escape it).

Same principle works for starting a program with a directory or file as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Try: `Ubuntu\ One` 
That may help it escape the space.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, either what wojox said, or put "Ubuntu One" in quotes, like that.

Comment: Thanks... the quotes fixed it. So simple when you know :)